# Loop through records and update paid status

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have three tables:

```
accounts:           `account_id`, `donations_req`, `payments_in, balance` 
donations_required: `donation_id`, `charity_id`, `account_id`, `amount`, `status`, `date`
payments:           `payment_id`, `account_id`, `amount`, `date`
```

I've managed to total up all `donations_req` for each donor and overwrite the `donations_req` field as well as payments for the `payments_in` field and then the balance (`payments_in - donations_req`).

However what I require is; with the `payments_in` total, to loop through the list of `donations_required` (sorted by `date`) and change the `status` to 1 for those which have been paid.

For instance: If I have 3 donations of $50 each and I deposit $120. The balance will be -$30 and the first two donations should be marked as paid.

So how do I mark off the statuses like this, considering having differing accounts altogether in the `donations_required` table.

Do I even need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stored procedure to process this but somehow you don't need to loop all the tables all you need to check is whether the person has sufficient balance or not. If they not you might update the status within the payment id and user id as well.

Hope it helps you :) GBU

Let's assume that this person has donated three charity funds which can be today or the next day instead.

First case, this person has donated 3 donations at the same time, so it can be done by the stored procedure to check whether this person has sufficient balance or not or in this case you allow this person to donate more than its balance

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `checkfunds`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `checkfunds`(IN `payment_id` VARCHAR(50), IN `account_id` VARCHAR(50), IN `amount` INT)
    COMMENT 'This procedure check the Balance'
BEGIN
DECLARE balance INT;

                SELECT BALANCE INTO balance from accounts where account_id = `account_id`
                IF balance > 0 AND balance > 'amount' THEN
                'allow'
                ELSEIF balance < 0 AND balance < 'amount' THEN
                'Not allow' <-- since you are here then update the status payment and your amount within your own calculation
                END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If the person has sufficient balance I can just mark all the records as paid i.e. a status of 1 but if I only have enough credit for say 2 out of 3 donations the first two should be marked as paid the last one 0 (unpaid / pending payment). I'm not quite sure I understand what exactly you're saying. What do you mean update status field with payment id and user id? And how would that help me?...I need to be able to filter on status so I need either 0 or 1

Comment: Updated, please check the answer

Comment: Sorry, my mistake for not being clear from the start. This is a custom system based around donations not funds. What I mean by that is the balance here represents the difference between donations required and funds paid so that if two donations are required from an account we will insert two donations_req records and the balance will be negative. That is to say when an person pays all his donations the balance should be zero

Comment: You might ask why not just update the donation statuses upon payments and the reason is that sometimes previous payments are removed or even donations_req. Therefore I can't rely on just updating fields...I have to recalculate everything from the first to the last record, if only when records are removed